# reduce inside function returns undefined (?)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

in this sample using reduce on array of objects works fine but when i insert it all into a function it starts to return undefined... it probably has to do with me not understanding how returning stuff from functions works

```js
const egArrOfObj = [
  {
    name:'tomato',
    
  },
  {
    name:'potato',
    
  },
 
];

 console.log(
   
   egArrOfObj
   .reduce((acc, curr) => {
       return [...acc, curr.name]
     } ,[] )
 );

const namesFunction = (arrOfObj) => {
    arrOfObj
      .reduce((acc, curr) => {
       return [...acc, curr.name]
 } ,[] )
 };

const names = namesFunction(egArrOfObj);

console.log(names)
```

Comment: typescript's not my exact field of expertise, but you don't appear to be returning anything from namesFunction

Comment: `reduce` works fine. It's your `namesFunction` that doesn't `return` anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add the `return` statement into your function then it will work as well.

Like the following:

```js
const egArrOfObj = [{
   name:'tomato',        
},
{
   name:'potato',
}];

const namesFunction = (arrOfObj) => {
    return arrOfObj.reduce((acc, curr) => {
       return [...acc, curr.name]
    }, [])
};

console.log(namesFunction(egArrOfObj));
```

I hope that helps!